# Sending an Email from google sheets only once

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

The code below works perfectly and sends the email I need it to send on an "OnChange" trigger. However, it sends an email for EVERY checked box in row 7 which is overload, it just needs to send an email for newly checked boxes.

Any advice on how to add a condition in the below code for this?

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Service');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (sheet.getRange(i,7).isChecked()){
   
    var name = sheet.getRange(i,1).getValue();
    var last = sheet.getRange(i,2).getValue();
    var body = name + " " + last
    var subject = 'New Service Item in Stock'
    MailApp.sendEmail('me@mycompany.com', subject, body);
    }
  }
}
```

I  haven't tried anything because there is nothing I could find online to get me in the right direction.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cKfLv.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try unchecking them after you send them:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('Service');
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 1; i--) {
    if (sheet.getRange(i, 7).isChecked() && sheet.getRange(i,8).getValue() != "Sent") {
      var name = sheet.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
      var last = sheet.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
      var body = name + " " + last
      var subject = 'New Service Item in Stock'
      MailApp.sendEmail('me@mycompany.com', subject, body);
      sheet.getRange(i, 8).setValue("Sent");
    }
  }
}
```

Performance improvement:

```
function sendEmails() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('Service');
  var vs = sh.getRange(2, 1, sh.getLastRow() - 1, sh.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  vs.forEach((r, i) => {
    if (sh.getRange(i + 2, 7).isChecked() && r[7] == "Sent") {
      let body = `${r[0]} ${r[1]}`;
      let subject = "New Service Item in Stock";
      MailApp.sendEmail('me@mycompany.com', subject, body);
      sh.getRange(i, 8).setValue("Sent");
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I can't, unfortunately. This is a whole company sheet and it needs to stay checked for people to see if something has been received.

Comment: Then you need to add another column to your spreadsheet to keep track of emails being sent.  Which column do you wish to add?

Comment: I'll add a column next to it for that so that would be column 8!

Comment: Your code could run much faster if you would use the data array for getting values.  If you provide an image of your spreadsheet I could implement those changes for you.

Comment: Added a photo but this script will be used for this sheet as well as another sheet.

Comment: Also - THANK YOU!! This so far is working perfectly. I did have to change the "&& sh.getRange(i,8)" part from sh to Sheet because it gave me an error code but it does exactly what I wanted.